# Find matching set of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following tables on SQL Server 2008R2

**MessageTable**

```
  ContrlNo|    LineNo     |    Msg
    1     |        1      |    Tiger1 Text
    1     |        2      |    Tiger1 Text
    1     |        3      |    Tiger1 Text
    1     |        4      |    Tiger1 Text
    2     |        1      |    Tiger1 Text1
    2     |        2      |    Tiger1 Text2
    2     |        3      |    Tiger1 Text3
    2     |        4      |    Tiger1 Text4
    3     |        1      |    Horse 1
    3     |        2      |    Horse 2
    3     |        3      |    Horse 3
    3     |        4      |    Horse 4
```

**RuleTable**

```
RuleNo|    MsgLineNo  | RuleStartingPos |    RuleMsg
1     |        1      |  1              |  Tiger1 Text
2     |        1      |  1              |  Tiger1 Text
2     |        3      |  1              |  Tiger1 Text3
```

For each set of ControlNo records in the MESSAGETABLE I would like to apply the rule from the RULETABLE and list the RULENo if any mataches.

If you see the RuleTable, the Rule 2 overlaps rule 1. And the requirement is to get the most matched RuleNo for each Control number. the expected result is,

```
ContrlNo | RuleNo
1   |   1 
2   |   2 
3   |   NULL
```

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: I don't understand your logic behind your expected results.  Can you explain more thoroughly?

Comment: We need to take all the records(LineNo, Msg) for each ContrlNo and match it against RuleTable(MsgLineNo, RuleMsg).

Comment: For example, if we take records belonging to ContrlNo 1 from MessageTable and match it against the RuleTable, RuleNo 1 matches 100 %. But the RuleNo 2 has two conditions and the second condition of the rule 2 doesn't match. So the result is, ContrlNo | RuleNo(1   |   1 ).                                 

if we take records belonging to ContrlNo 2 from MessageTable and match it against the RuleTable, RuleNo 1 matches 100 %. But the RuleNo 2 has two conditions and they both match 100% too. AS we need the maximum matching rule, So in this case the result is, ContrlNo | RuleNo(2   |   2 ).

Comment: @Jay, did the query given by me working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following will retrieve the listed results: it will show a control number with the associated rule that has the most matching lines (if, as in your first case, two rules have an equal number of matches, it will check the MatchPercent).

```
SELECT MT.ContrlNo, r.RuleNo, r.MatchPercent
FROM
  MessageTable MT
   LEFT JOIN 
    (
      SELECT 
        ContrlNo,
        RuleNo, 
        MatchedRules / AvailableRules AS MatchPercent,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContrlNo ORDER BY MatchedRules DESC, MatchedRules / AvailableRules DESC) AS rn
      FROM 
        (
          SELECT 
            ContrlNo, 
            R.RuleNo, 
            COUNT(*) as MatchedRules,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RuleTable WHERE RuleTable.RuleNo = R.RuleNo) + 0.0 AS AvailableRules
          FROM 
              MessageTable M
               INNER JOIN 
              RuleTable R ON 
                  M.[LineNo] = R.MsgLineNo AND 
                  SUBSTRING(M.Msg,R.RuleStartingPos,LEN(R.RuleMsg)) LIKE '%' + R.RuleMsg + '%'
          GROUP BY M.ContrlNo, R.RuleNo
        ) q
     ) r ON 
    MT.ContrlNo = r.ContrlNo AND
    r.rn = 1
GROUP BY MT.ContrlNo, r.RuleNo, r.MatchPercent
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9659d/22)

Answer (score 0):

First subquery is getting total Matched rules and second sub query is getting total rules, when these two conditions are matched then we show the RuleNo other wise NULL as we are using `LEFT JOIN`

```
Select A.ContrlNo, ISNULL(T.RuleNo,0) as RuleNo FROM
(  select ContrlNo, COUNT(R.RuleNo) as MatchedRules
   FROM Messages M
   LEFT JOIN Rules R
   on M.[LineNo] = R.MsgLineNo
   and SUBSTRING(M.Msg,R.RuleStartingPos,LEN(R.RuleMsg)) = R.RuleMsg
   AND M.ContrlNo = R.RuleNo
GROUP BY M.ContrlNo) A
LEFT JOIN (  
    select COUNT(MsgLineNo) as TotalRules, RuleNo 
    from Rules R1  
    group by RuleNo) T
    ON A.MatchedRules = T.TotalRules
```

Comment: Select A.ContrlNo, T.RuleNo FROM
(  select ContrlNo, COUNT(R.RuleNo) as MatchedRules
   FROM MessageTable M
   LEFT JOIN RuleTable R
   on M.[LineNo] = R.MsgLineNo
   and M.Msg = R.RuleMsg
   GROUP BY M.ContrlNo) A
LEFT JOIN ( 
       select COUNT(MsgLineNo) as TotalRules, RuleNo
       from RuleTable R1 
       group by RuleNo) T
ON A.MatchedRules = T.TotalRules    for matching the message I need to do something like the following,    SUBSTRING(M.Msg,R.RuleStartingPos,LEN(R.RuleMsg)) = R.RuleMsg      we need to get most matched RuleNo foreach ContrlNo.

Comment: @Jay, added that condition to the clause, it does give max matched rule no.

Comment: Thanks.... but we can not compare  M.ContrlNo = R.RuleNo... They are totally different